# dynamically providing default input to calling script from a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a shell-script main_script.sh, which will in term call 3 other scripts (a1.sh,a2.sh,a3.sh).
Now on execution of a1.sh/a2.sh/a3.sh I need to answer some verbose with Y/N.

I know that each of a1.sh/a2.sh/a3.sh will need 2 Y/N.

How can I implement main_script.sh,so I don't have to answer Y/N requests while execution?

Comment: Note a1.sh,a2.sh,a3.sh are inside main_script.sh.
main_script.sh will execute a1.sh,a2.sh,a3.sh

and for all the verbose I have to enter Y only.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the scripts are written.  You mentioned each script needing two `Y`.  I presume that each `Y` will need to be followed by an enter key (newline).  In this case, it could be as simple as using the following for `main_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $'Y\nY\n' | bash a1.sh
echo $'Y\nY\n' | bash a2.sh
echo $'Y\nY\n' | bash a3.sh
```

Above, the `echo` command sends two `Y` and newline characters to each of the scripts.  You can adjust this as needed.

Some scripts will insist that interactive input come from the terminal, not stdin.  Such scripts are harder, but not impossible, to fool.  For them, use [`expect`/`pexpect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

#### More details

Let's look in more detail at one of those commands:

```
echo $'Y\nY\n' | bash a1.sh
```

The `|` is the pipe symbol.  It connects the standard out of the `echo` command to the standard input of the `a1.sh` command.  If `a1.sh` is amenable, this may allow us to pre-answer any and all questions that `a1.sh` asks.

In this case, the output from the `echo` command is `$'Y\nY\n'`.  This is a bash shell syntax meaning `Y`, followed by newline character, denoted by `\n`, followed by `Y`, followed by newline, `\n`.  A newline character is the same thing that the `enter` or `return` key generates.

#### Using `expect`

If your script does not accept input on stdin, then `expect` can be used to automate the interaction with script.   As an example:

```
#!/bin/sh

expect <<EOF1
spawn a1.sh
expect "?"
send "Y\r"
expect "?"
send "Y\r"
sleep 1
EOF1

expect <<EOF2
spawn a2.sh
expect "?"
send "Y\r"
expect "?"
send "Y\r"
sleep 1
EOF2
```

Comment: #!/bin/sh
echo $'Y\nY\n' | pkgrm pkg1
echo $'Y\nY\n' | pkgrm pkg2
echo $'Y\nY\n' | pkgrm pkg3

echo $'Y\nY\n' | pkgadd -d . new_pkg1
echo $'Y\nY\n' | pkgadd -d . new_pkg2
echo $'Y\nY\n' | pkgadd -d . new_pkg3

I was using like this.
But I think something is going wrong.

"Do you want to remove this package? [y,n,?,q]         ERROR: Please enter yes or no.
"

Comment: For cases when redirecting stdin is not adequate, I have added to the answer information on using `expect` to automate scripts.  If there continue to be problems, I will need more exact information on the scripts' interactions.